# Oxidation of diols to dialdehydes

Tags: alcohols, organic-oxidation

How could 1,4-butanediol be converted to 1,4-butandial (succinic aldehyde)? I thought of simple oxidation with $\ce{CuO}$ but apparently it yields gamma-butyrolactone according to [erowid](https://erowid.org/archive/rhodium/chemistry/gbl.synthesis.microgram.html#refs)
and this paper$\ce{^{[1]}}$. Could increasing the pH result in the formation of 1,4-butandial?

$\ce{[1]}$: Romaric Gérardy, Romain Morodo, Julien Estager, Patricia Luis, Damien P. Debecker, Jean-Christophe M. Monbaliu, Sustaining the Transition from a Petrobased to a Biobased Chemical Industry with Flow Chemistry, Topics in Current Chemistry, 10.1007/s41061-018-0222-3, 377, 1, (**2018**). ([DOI](https://doi.org/10.1002/14356007.a04_495))

Comment: Alternatively, I am quite sure that PCC would stop at the aldehyde stage.

Here, a complex diol with a 4-carbon chain is oxidized to dialdehyde with the "similar" PDC
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0957416610008530?via%3Dihub

Comment: DMSO-based oxidation is another valid and widely cited in literature approach (eg. Swern Oxidation)

Comment: Difficult stuff to handle as it is prone to polymerisation. Best stored as 2,5-dimethoxytetrahydrofuran which is functionally equivalent for synthetic purposes.

Comment: True; speaking of that, wouldn't it be easier to convert easily accesssible tetrahydrofuran into 2,5-dimethoxytetrahydrofuran directly? How could I substitute a methoxy group into 2nd and 5th position?

Comment: THF can be chlorinated at low temps with UV light below -10C to 2,5-dichloro-THF (ref here https://www.chempap.org/file_access.php?file=311a109.pdf) and then reacted with MeONa/MeOH to give 2,5-dimethoxy-THF. I would not call this an easy option, given that 2,5-dimethoxy-THF is widely commercially available

Comment: Chromium-based oxidations will give butyrolactone. Swern-type oxidations are a better choice because both hydroxyls are derivatized before base (Et3N) effects the formation of the aldehyde groups.

Comment: Oxone and TEMPO,  maybe with PTC if phases are immiscible?